# How to preserve ratio an uploaded image in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code and need to preserve aspect ratio of an uploaded images in my script:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<?Php
require "includes/config.php";
set_time_limit (0);
$max_file_size=8000; // This is in KB

@$gal_id=$_POST['cat_id'];
@$todo=$_POST['todo'];
$userid=$_SESSION['art_id'];

/// for thumbnail image size //
$n_width=300;
$n_height=300;
$required_image_width=890; // Width of resized image after uploading

if($todo=='upload'){
if(!($gal_id > 0)){
echo "Selectează o categorie ";
exit;
}

while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
$dt=date("Y-m-d");

$sql=$dbo->prepare("insert into lucrari (cat_id,poza,art_id)      values('$gal_id','$value','$userid')");
if($sql->execute()){
$id=$dbo->lastInsertId();
$file_name=$id."_".$value;
}
else{//echo mysql_error();
echo "O problemă pe server. Contactaţi administratorul! ";
exit;}

$add = $path_upload.$file_name;   // upload directory path is set

copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);     //  upload the file to the server

chmod("$add",0777);                 // set permission to the file.

$sql=$dbo->prepare("update lucrari set poza = '$file_name' WHERE lucrare_id=$id");
$sql->execute();

//////////ThumbNail creation //////////////////

if(file_exists($add)){
$tsrc=$path_thumbnail.$file_name;
$im=ImageCreateFromJPEG($add);
$width=ImageSx($im); // Original picture width is stored
$height=ImageSy($im); // Original picture height is stored
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height);
imageCopyResized($newimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);
ImageJpeg($newimage,$tsrc);
chmod("$tsrc",0777);
}// end of if
////////Ending of thumb nail ////////

/////////// Resize if width is more than 890 /////

if($required_image_width < $width){
$adjusted_height=round(($required_image_width/$width) * $height);
$im=ImageCreateFromJPEG($add);
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($required_image_width,$adjusted_height);
imageCopyResized($newimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$required_image_width,$adjusted_height,$width,$height);
ImageJpeg($newimage,$add);
chmod("$add",0777);
}

echo " &nbsp; <a href=poza.php?lucrare_id=$id target='new'><img src='$tsrc'></a>";
//sleep(5);
}
}

?>
```

What I want is to edit this script to preserve ratio of images instead of using:

```
$n_width=300;
$n_height=300;
```

what happend with 
    $n_width=300;
    $n_height=300;
in my case, what do i need to write there instead of values?
thank you

Comment: First you'd need to check if the source picture is in portrait or landscape mode (eg. if `imagesx(...)  > imagesy(...)`). If it is in portrait mode: Set `$n_width = 300 / imagesy(...) * imagesx(...);` and `$n_height = 300;`. If it's in landscape mode vice versa. This way, the longer side gets resized to 300px and the shorter accordingly to keep aspect ratio.

Comment: i'ved try but i missed something because isn't work. I am not advanced in php so thats i put question here. i need to understand that code first of all, mechanism of preserve ratio of pictures....

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is get the width to height ratio. For example a 480x640 portrait image is 3:4, or 3/4, or 0.75. You then need to set your largest dimension (in this case, height of 640) to your desired height (in your example, 300). You then need to apply that 0.75 ratio (to keep the "aspect ratio") to the smallest dimension (the width of 480): 480 * 0.75 = 360px.

A simple way to remember what to do, is that you're "making the big dimension small, and the smallest dimension even smaller [by multiplying it with the ratio fraction]".

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
<?php
// Set the maximum width and height we want to use
$n_width = 300;
$n_height = 300;

// Get the width to height ratio
$ratio = 0;
// Determine if the image is landscape...
if ($width > $height)
{
    $ratio = $height / $width;
    $n_height *= $ratio;
}
// ...Or portrait
else
{
    $ratio = $width / $height;
    $n_width *= $ratio;
}
?>
```